# What's the meaning of "not no small feat"?

Tags: american-english, slang, negation, double-negation

I didn't understand meaning of **"not no small feat"** in this sentence:

> I want y'all to meet Deltron Zero, hero, **not no small feat.**

From [Deltron 3030's song *3030*](https://genius.com/Deltron-3030-3030-lyrics) Verse 1, 2nd line

I know what **"no small feat"** means but adding **"not"** the sentence makes me confused.

Comment: ***"not no small feat"*** doesn't sound remotely idiomatic to me. The standard expression is to say something [***IS no mean feat.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+no+mean+feat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) But nobody would normally introduce "double negation" into that - not least because ***mean*** (small, trivial) already effectively "negates" ***feat*** (usually, a ***substantial*** accomplishment), so you end up with a "triple negation", which is just getting silly.

Comment: ...my mistake. Apparently [Americans have started using ***small*** here.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+no+mean+feat%2Cis+no+small+feat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) But [Brits are still sticking with ***mean.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+no+mean+feat%2Cis+no+small+feat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: It sounds like AAVE, where double and even triple negatives occur. I was once in a lecture where the speaker started talking about double negatives meaning a positive, sometimes, but there was no double positive that had a negative meaning. Someone in the audience yelled out, in a skeptical tone of voice, Yeah yeah.

Comment: We're going to have to rewrite the Stones' classic for the 21st century - "I don't can't not get not no Satisfaction…not" ;)

Comment: It appears to be intentionally garbled speech.

Comment: @Tim That's an old linguist joke, were you really at that lecture? https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/double-positive.html

Comment: This is certainly dialectic, but it's not particular to AAVE. Double negatives are *very* common in many American spoken dialects.

Comment: It was probly _no small feet_, especially if Deltron Zero has big feet.

Comment: *this ain’t no small feat* ... *this ain’t no disco* ... this ain’t no problem.

Comment: @Barmar:  Yes, it took place at a small college in the suburbs of Philadelphia. No doubt a few linguists from UPenn were in the audience.

Comment: @Tim — Which lecture were you at? This one is the OG: https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=3810783

Comment: @TinfoilHat  This lecture was at Swarthmore College circa 1977.

Answer (score 2):

This is rap music, so all bets (and rules) are off.

In this case, the double negative is being used as an intensifier of the single negative, "no small feat". On the one hand, rap in general doesn't make distinctions like double negatives cancelling out, and on the other hand the meaning is established in context.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence ***could*** contain the rhetorical figure called litotes. In order to do that, simply reword your sentence as follows:

- I want y'all to meet Deltron Zero, hero, which is no small feat.

However, I must ask you: Do you want to say that **getting someone to meet** the hero Deltron Zero was no small feat on your part?

If so, then another way of wording your sentence could be as follows:

> I want y'all to meet the hero Deltron Zero in person, which was not a
> small feat on my part.

In other words, getting hero Deltron Zero to meet people took a great deal of effort on your part.

***Litotes*** is a kind of understatement. The words *no* and *small* are meant to  understate the words "a big feat." If I had to guess, I think the use of litotes is for some people an alternative to the "normal"--and sometimes habitual--way of saying something is big.

Dr. Luke, the author of the New Testament book of Acts of the Apostles used litotes:

> In the morning, there was no small commotion among the soldiers as to
> what had become of Peter (Acts 12:18 NIV).

The apostle Paul also used litotes:

> For you yourselves know how you ought to follow our example. We were
> not idle when we were with you . . . (2 Thessalonians 3:7 NIV).

Paul then included the positive spin of "not idle" in the next verse:

> On the contrary, we worked night and day, **laboring and toiling** so that
> we would not be a burden to any of you(2 Thessalonians 3:8b NIV, my emphasis).

Comment: This explains "not a small feat" and "no small feat", but not the double negative "not not small feat".